# Hacer que si un checkbox no ha sido seleccionado no se pueda imprimir en la pantalla con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito hacer un checkbox de "Agregar al carrito", ya logré que los valores se imprimieran en la pantalla, pero cuando los mando imprimir sin que el checkbox este seleccionado se sigue imprimiendo el valor del mismo, ¿como puedo hacer que eso no suceda?.

```
function valores() {
    n1 = (document.getElementById("opciones").value);
    n2 = (document.getElementById("vehicle").value);

   //Lista de datos capturados
    t = document.createTextNode( n2+ ":" + " " +n1 );
    parrafin.appendChild(t);
    parrafin.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));




  }
```

```html
<h1>Pruebas uwu</h1>
  <form id="miFormulario">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Informacion Personal:</legend>
      <div class=""><img src="img/doritos.jpg" width="70">Doritos - $10<label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle" value="Doritos"><strong>Añadir al carrito</strong>
              </label></div>
      <div class="container2">
               <select id="opciones" name="opciones">
                  <option value="Cantidad">Cantidad</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                  <option value="5">5</option>
                  <option value="6">6</option>
                  <option value="7">7</option>
                  <option value="8">8</option>
                  <option value="9">9</option>
                  <option value="10">10</option>
                  <option value="11">11</option>
                  <option value="12">12</option>
                  <option value="13">13</option>
                  <option value="14">14</option>
                  <option value="15">15</option>
                  <option value="16">16</option>
                  <option value="17">17</option>
                  <option value="18">18</option>
                  <option value="19">19</option>
                  <option value="20">20</option>
               </select>
             </div><br>
    <div id="div1">
    <p id="parrafin"></p> 
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Listar Datos Capturados" onclick="valores();">
  </form>
```

Ya intente con todo pero nada me sale, si pudieran ayudarme estaría totalmente agradecido...[image: Esta es la pagina]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validar el valor del checkbox antes de imprimir

```
function valores() {
    var checkElement = document.getElementById('vehicle');
    if(checkElement.checked){
        n1 = (document.getElementById("opciones").value);
        n2 = (document.getElementById("vehicle").value);

        //Lista de datos capturados
        t = document.createTextNode( n2+ ":" + " " +n1 );
        parrafin.appendChild(t);
        parrafin.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
    else{
        alert("Seleccione añadir al carrito");
    }

}
```